# Is there a time limit to how far out I can pull an event using Google Cal API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to pull events off of a public calendar and seem stuck within a 6 month range, and I am not finding documentation that would verify this as a limit. I wouldn't have thought there would be a limit, do you know of one?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Calendar API reference is here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

I don't see any mention of a limit int he [Events.List](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) operation. Is it possible that the results are on a separate "page" and you need to make another request to get the second page of results?